# mac automatically selecting text after delete

Tags: macos, highlighting

Running OS X 10.9, though the issue occurred in 10.8 as well, and I've noticed it in Xcode and Netbeans. When I highlight some text and delete it, usually some variable or string with in some code, the selected area stays selected, basically selecting the next set of characters. So when I continue typing, I type over that bit of selected code.

For example, say I have the following bit of code selected between the brackets:
The quick [brown fox] jumps over the lazy dog.

Now after I delete the text, the following text between the brackets will be selected:
The quick [ jumps ov]er the lazy dog.

The expected result would be to have no text selected and the cursor simply at the the 'J' (or space before) in the word jumps.

I've searched for this type of behavior in Netbeans and Xcode, but haven't found anything, so I'm concluding the behavior is with in OS X, but I haven't found anyone else with this issue nor how to remedy it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Woa... I have never seen this in years of Xcoding. Sounds annoying.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting in Safe mode? That sounds very strange, and it's certainly a behavior that I would have noticed over the past few years if it was happening on my machine.

Comment: for me, this happens in all text boxes. (osx yosemite)

Comment: I've been using Yosemite for a while now and haven't experienced the problem with XCode or any other text field or application; however, I haven't been using Netbeans at all. So maybe I had something on my mac, who knows. Glad to see I wasn't the only one with that issue though.

Comment: I have this issue throughout my Mac and it is driving me crazy.

Comment: I have been having the same problem since years and as of today it is still there and reproducable. Example Sentence "abc def ...". I double tap on "abc", it's selected then I delete it with backspace key. Afterwards "def" is selected!!!. It is one of the most annoying things on Macbook. The close second is that you don't have keyboard backlight on startup if your macbook is encrypted. So it is a nightmare to enter your password in a dark room.

Answer (score 0):

It´s an old issue, but still persists. This answer does not provide a solution but a recording of the issue happening in mail, which may help finding a reason. First you see a successful mark-and-overwrite, then a failing one. After that, I hit undo and redo several times, to show that the issue was recorded in the editing history. See the video in the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/av3jtp7knhh8wki/Text_input_bug.mov?dl=0